# horizontal alignment of 3 divs on the same line

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to get 3 divs to appear on the same line in the formation: left - centered - right

For example, one div left-aligned, the next one centered, and the last one right-aligned.

Does anyone know how to do this? I have 2 div left and right aligned, but if I introduce a centered div in the middle it moves the rightmost div onto a new line.

Comment: Please post your HTML/CSS.

Comment: maybe this can help http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
.left-col {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
}
.center-col {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.right-col {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

<div class="left-col">purple</div>
<div class="center-col">monkey</div>
<div class="right-col">dishwasher</div>
```

Comment: I updated your code. it is working fine. not sure why you get downvote though.   http://jsfiddle.net/Y2aFA/1/

Comment: What happens if he puts borders on the divs?

Comment: @Mr_Green, I removed the clears. @j08691, borders weren't part of the question. However, borders could be added on an inner element or by using `box-sizing`. It all depends on what browsers need to be supported.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to do that is using any framework. For example: 960gs -> http://960.gs/.

With this framework you can set columns in your page. Example here: http://960.gs/demo.html

Comment: I'm not convinced that you need to introduce a framework to achieve something that can be done in just a few lines of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you may use : display:flex;

A tool to help you produce the code and undertand how it works : http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

example in your case it could be :

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -moz-box-pack: justify;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
    }

/*
    Legacy Firefox implementation treats all flex containers
    as inline-block elements.
*/

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.flex-container {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

}
```

other way to fake an `horizontal-align-content:justify` (this is made up rule ).
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/Babcs

with little less CSS to adapt for older IES

```
.justify {
  text-align:justify;
  line-height:0;
}
.justify:after, .justify span.ie {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.justify > div {
  text-align:left;
  line-height:1.2em;
  display:inline-block;
  *display:inline;
  zoom:1;
  width:50%;
  border:solid;
}
.justify > div:nth-child(odd) {
  width:20%;
}
```

Float and display:table have already been discussed :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make a table with div's? :)

ok it has to be something like:

```
<div style="float:left; width:20%;"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%;"></div>
<div style="float:left; width:20%;"></div>
```

this should be on a css rule though has you probably will want to change the width of each div

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
body {                    /* or parent element of below child elements */
    position: relative;
}
.left-col {
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}
.center-col {
    width: 10%;
    height:100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    text-align:center;
}
.right-col {
    width: 25%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align: right;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2aFA/2/)**

Care must be taken that the sum of the widths of the three elements must not be greater than 100%. if you want to use borders for these elements then create child elements for each element and give `position: absolute` to them. Something like this:

```
.childDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;                 /* acts as border-top for parent element*/
    bottom: 2px;              /* border-bottom */
    left: 2px;                /* border-left */
    right: 2px;               /* border-right */
    background-color: black;  /* acts as border-color for parent element */
}
```